# Probability of difference of two numbers between 0-60 being not greater than 10

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

two real numbers x and y between 0 and 60 (both inclusive), what is the probability of difference of two numbers being not greater than 10? Ans given is: 11/36
My analysis is as follows:
Let us presume: x>=y, and x-y<=10, i.e. 0 to 10
then for x being 0 to 9, y can be {0}, {0.1}, ...{0,1,....9}
i.e. 1+2+...10 = 55 possibilities
now if x = 10-60, y could be {0-10}, {1-11}, ... {50-60}
i.e. 11 possibilities for 10-60 i.e 51 possibilities
so 51x11+55
=616
x and y could be interchangeable
so 616x2 = 1232
x=y case has been counted twice
so 1232-61=1171
total possibilities : 61x61= 3721
so 1171/3721=0.3147

Am I doing any wrong?

Comment: The numbers $x$ and $y$ *need not be integers*.  The chosen numbers have *continuous uniform distribution*, so their joint density is $\frac{1}{3600}$ on the $60\times 60$ square. You should be able to find the probability using a *geometric* argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding the suggestion of A.Nicolas, you can imagine the two points as the coordinate of a point $(x,y)$ on a square $60\times 60$. Since $x$ and $y$ are uniform at random the point $(x,y)$ will be uniform on all the square.

Then you have to understand which area of this square satisfies $|x-y|\le 10$.

I help you with a picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [numbersaplenty.com](http://numbersaplenty.com/data/grafic.png))</sub>

It's easy to see that this area is equal to $60^2-50^2=1100$, so the ratio between the areas is $1100/3600 = 11/36$.

Answer (score 0):

f(x) = 1/60

integrating f(x) from 0 to 60, there is a variable range the second variable can be in, r, giving prob r/60

from 0 to 10 it is x + 10 (10 ahead spaces, and x behind)
from 10 to 50 it is 20 
from 50 to 60 it is 10 + 60 - x

$\frac{1}{3600}(\int_0^{10} (x + 10) dx + \int_{10}^{50} 20 dx + \int_{50}^{60}(10 + (60 -x)dx)$

$=  \frac{1}{3600}([\frac{1}{2}x^2+ 10x]_0^{10} + [20x]_{10}^{50} + [70x - \frac{1}{2}x^2]_{50}^{60}) $

$= \frac{1}{3600} ((50 + 100 - 0)  + (1000 - 200) + 4200 - 1800 - (3500 - 1250)) $

$= 1100/3600 = 11/36 $